# Running webapp2 app in a multiple WSGI apps set up with Werkzeug

Tags: python, wsgi, webapp2, werkzeug

I am trying to run a django app and a webapp2 app together in one python interpreter. I'm using werkzeug for that as described [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/appdispatch/).

Here's my sample code.

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from django_app import application as djangoapp
from webapp2_app import application as webapp2app

application = DispatcherMiddleware(djangoapp, {
    '/backend':     webapp2app
})
```

After doing this, I would expect all requests to /backend should be treated by the webapp2 app as /. But it treats the requests as /backend. This work fines with other WSGI apps using django or flask. The problem only appears with webapp2 apps. Does anyone have any suggestions how to overcome this? Is there any other way I can achieve my purpose without using werkzeug for serving multiple WSGI apps under one domain?

Comment: I haven't used webapp2 before, but you can probably work around it by wrapping your "actual" routes in [PathPrefixRoute](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/routing.html#path-prefix-routes). As for an actual (correct) fix, can you include how you're instantiating webapp2app and its routes?

Comment: @AdamKG PathPrefixRoute is not a perfect solution for me. It will route all the request to right controllers for sure. But I have to modify a lot of code inside the controllers (eg redirects) and templates to get everything right.

And I am instantiating the webapp2app in the normal way i.e. `app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(urls, debug=feconf.DEBUG)` where urls is the url routing map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DispatcherMiddleware` fabricates environments for your apps and especially `SCRIPT_NAME`. Django can deal with it with configuration varibale `FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = ''` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#force-script-name)).

With Webapp2 it's slightly more complicated. You can create subclass of `webapp2.WSGIApplication` and override `__call__()` method and force `SCRIPT_NAME` to desired value. So in your `webapp2_app.py` it could be like this

```
import webapp2

class WSGIApp(webapp2.WSGIApplication):

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''
        return super(WSGIApp, self).__call__(environ, start_response)

# app = WSGIApp(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That makes sense. To clarify things a bit, what is the desired value of SCRIPT_NAME? And also, seeing the source of DispatcherMiddleware I see the \_\_call\_\_ method tries to change PATH_INFO as well. Do I need to do anything about that?

Comment: TL;DR: Just set `SCRIPT_NAME = ''` and don't touch `PATH_INFO`. For basic info about CGI and its variables see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface. As for your question webapp2 matches routes over `request.path` which is defined [here](https://github.com/moraes/webapp-improved/blob/master/lib/WebOb-1.0.8/webob/request.py#L287). As you can see it is `script_name + path_info`.

Comment: This seems to be the right solution. But if I use the Subclass to create the app as you have suggested, I am getting application_iter = None at https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/blob/master/werkzeug/serving.py#L165
But if I edit the webapp2 source directly and put the `environ['SCRIPT_NAME'] = ''` line there directly, everything works fine.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `return` statement :/ Updated answer

Comment: Woot, that was kind of obvious. Thanks for the help :-)